# problem with pre-annotations (yolo v5) in label studio

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, annotations, object-detection, data-annotations

I am trying to use annotations from my Yolo v5 model in label-studio. I was able to bring the annotations to label-studio and show them. The problem is the inaccuracy in the labels displayed by label-studio (I have images generated from Yolo to how the predictions should look like). The only transformation I did to the x, y, width, height data obtained from yolo is multiplying by 100.

Predictions from yolo:
[YOLO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm0ti.jpg)
label-studio:
[label-studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p68JN.jpg)

Comment: How did you convert YOLO to LS JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use label-studio-converter for this: https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-converter/pull/46

Most likely you incorrectly calculated coordinates, the correct code is here: https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-converter/blob/master/label_studio_converter/imports/yolo.py#L85

Answer (score 0):

> only transformation I did to the x, y, width, height data obtained from yolo is multiplying by 100

Building on @Max answer you can use the following formulas (from [here](https://github.com/heartexlabs/label-studio-converter/blob/master/label_studio_converter/imports/yolo.py#L85)) to convert yolo coordinates to label studio compatible coordinates

```
x_lbstdio = (x-width/2)*100
y_lbstdio = (y-height/2)*100
w_lbstdio = w*100
h_lbstdio = h*100
```

Note the only change being subtracting half of width and half of height from x and y respectively before multiplying by 100